# The code works in some cases but gives different outputs based on the sequence of the input

Tags: java, string, if-statement, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

Expected Output should be as such:

```
Download
String: Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!
Double: 3.1415
Int: 42
```

My code gives different outputs based on what input I put in at first.
If possible please explain where I went wrong.
Thank you in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int   count = 1;
        String typeCase = "";



        while (count<4) {

            if (!sc.hasNext("[0-9]+[\\.]?[0-9]*") || sc.hasNext(":ascii:")) {

                typeCase = "String:";
                count++;

            } else if (sc.hasNextInt()) {

                typeCase = "Int:";
                count++;

            } else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {


                typeCase = "Double:";
                count++;

            }

            switch (typeCase) {
                case "String:":
                    typeCase = "String: ";
                    System.out.println(typeCase + sc.nextLine());
                    break;
                case "Int:":
                    typeCase = "Int: ";
                     System.out.println(typeCase + sc.nextInt());
                    break;
                case "Double:":
                    typeCase = "Double: ";
                     System.out.println(typeCase + sc.nextDouble());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide specific input, actual output and expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the input should be:

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, the input should be an int, double, and  String. The expected output should be as such                                                                                       
          String: Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!
          Double: 3.1415
          Int: 42                                                                                                            
                       Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: I need to put several different inputs into the scanner and receive sorted output based on the data type I provide. Sorry for not being clear and thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I think changing your switch case block as below should solve your problem if you are sure that integers and double inputs will be present in their own line(if not, you will get the hint from this solution on restructuring your code to achieve such cases as well). Use sc.nextLine() after each sc.nextInt() and sc.nextDouble() because these methods will not read the newline character.
**Edit:** Editing the answer since you seem to want to print the output in the order as String,double and int. You can temporarily store the value from the scanner and print it later in whichever order you want.
**Please note that I have now removed the switch case**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int   count = 1;
            String typeCaseString = "";
            String typeCaseInt = "";
            String typeCaseDouble = "";

            while (count<4) {

                if (!sc.hasNext("[0-9]+[\\.]?[0-9]*") || sc.hasNext(":ascii:")) {

                    typeCaseString = "String:"+sc.nextLine();
                    count++;

                } else if (sc.hasNextInt()) {

                    typeCaseInt = "Int:"+sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    count++;

                } else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                    typeCaseDouble = "Double:"+sc.nextDouble();
                     sc.nextLine();
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(typeCaseString);
            System.out.println(typeCaseDouble);
            System.out.println(typeCaseInt);

    }
```